# error handling in unoconv

Tags: bash, shell, unoconv

I have a script that automatically converts excel file from xls to csv using unoconv. From time to time I'm getting this error.

```
line 174: 21023 Segmentation fault  unoconv -f csv "$FILES"
```

I want to be able to handle any error that occurs upon conversion. I've tried adding this to the script.

```
unoconv -f csv "$FILES"
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "error encountered when converting from xls to csv"
else
    echo "Successfully converted to csv"
fi
```

My problem is that. Even if I encounter that error. The error message is not being reflected. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: try to grep "Segmentation fault" string, probably the posix status is not affected by the abort

Comment: may I ask how do i grep the Segmentation fault? grep it from where?

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
unoconv -f csv "$FILES" 2>&1 | grep -i "Segmentation fault" &>/dev/null \
&& echo "error encountered when converting from xls to csv" \
|| echo "Successfully converted to csv"
```

Comment: hmm. i was thinking of doing this approach `convert_status=`unoconv -f csv "$FILES"`` then if `[ $conver_status != ""] then echo "error_encountered"` .. what do you think?

Comment: @user2058738 i don't see difference between your codes: they do the same, so i'm expecting the same result